How To Find DexTool Trade Transaction Hash On BscScan / EtherScan
I'm presently trying to hunt down a rug pull of a fake PRCL token. I realize this is Binance Smart Chain, not Ethereum, but there's no community for Binance Smart Chain and it should hopefully be fairly similar.
Here's a link to a DexTools summary of a trading pair for the token.
https://www.dextools.io/app/en/bnb/pair-explorer/0x2184114c6678f558292bc3d8ae37e422bb188e13?t=1714069044841
According to the history if you scroll down, there are tons of trade transactions, including this one which I believe is the rug pull:
"Apr 15 20:06:40
sell
$0.0₁₀8617
$172,350.50
0.0₁₂1573
2,000,000,029,277,270"
However, there are no transaction hashes and I'm not even sure what timezone that time is in.
So I thought I would go to look up on BSCScan (very similar to EtherScan) and find the transaction.
The token contract is apparently at 0x8db24fed8461cd656089ea3587bc340884fabad1.
I would assume I could go to BSCScan and look up the transactions for that contract. However, they all appear to be approvals, and failed transfers.
https://bscscan.com/address/0x8db24fed8461cd656089ea3587bc340884fabad1
When I look at token transfers there's only a single transaction there.
https://bscscan.com/address/0x8db24fed8461cd656089ea3587bc340884fabad1#tokentxns
This feels kind of hopeless at the moment. I feel like there's something fundamental that I'm missing. Any idea what I should be doing to find this transaction?
